# Metrics for Storage Account entities not retrieved properly

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues

I use Azure management URL to retrieve the metrics for Storage account entities. Whenever I try to get the metrics for storage account entities, setting time granularity to 15 minutes(PT15M), metrics are retrieved only for the first quarter i.e. say 09:00 to 09:15. 
For remaining three quarters null is returned, then I get the correct metrics again for 10:00 to 10:15.

When I use Azure portal to do the same, setting time granularity to 15 minutes(PT15M) metrics are retrieved for 1 hour(PT1H).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QueueCount is capacity metric. The minimum time grain supported is PT1H. It means that Storage emits the metric value once a hour. So it's expected behavior. You can find definition in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-metrics-in-azure-monitor, or use Azure Monitor metric definition API to see metricAvailabilities, reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/metricdefinitions_list